# How to check if Facebook API made a successful query?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you check if the return of the facebook API query is successful?

```
$qry = $this->facebook->api(array(
   'method'      =>  'fql.multiquery',
   'queries'     =>  $fql,
   'access_token'=>  $facebook['access_token']
));
```

There are some instance where you get a socket 443 error.
How do you catch this and simply requery in-case of the error?

Comment: [try {} catch() {}](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) ?

Comment: @j0k +1 for the desc of your link ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FB PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) throws exceptions when an error occurs (you can see this by [reading the code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L966) or looking at the [example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php#L35)). So the idea is

```
try {
    $qry = $this->facebook->api(...);
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // handle the error
}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to replicate the `Unknown SSL protocol error` since it only happes when you least expect it but is the `catch` handler will simply execute anything inside it? Does the program continues after the `catch` handler?

Comment: @MegaNairda: Yes and yes. Read the PHP manual on exceptions to familiarize yourself with how this feature works.